# Arguments missing in the pattern

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I am trying to use a reg expression to do a "Find and Replace" to strip the blank lines and return only the two lines containing my code (but leaving the line breaks intact) from my .cs file .For that I found a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199691/regular-expression-to-match-any-empty-line-or-any-line-starting-with-a-specified) But when I type the `(?m)^([ \t]*|;.*)(\r?\n|$)` I am getting  error Arguments missing in the pattern .What's wrong with the way I am using this expression

[image]

Comment: An example input and output would help. The problem however is that Visual Studio versions before 2012 use [their own, POSIX-based regex flavor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.100).aspx) which is not the same as .NET's. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx) provides a conversion guide (intended for the other way round, but it should help you anyway).

Comment: [Here is a rant by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html) about the problem, that might help you as well in converting the expression (I would help you with that, but I don't have my VS2010 any more to actually test any solutions).

Answer (score 0):

`"^$\n"`  worked for me( vs2010 ). I found this ans from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/117825/Remove-blank-lines-from-code-in-Visual-Studio)